How can I ensure that $x \iff p \land q$ here?
Say I am writing a Boolean formula in which only $\land$ is between clauses, and only $\oplus$ is between literals in the clauses. How can I make it such that an assignment of variables satisfies the formula only if, for variables $x,p,q$,     $ \ \ x  \iff p \land q$?
My problem is that I'm struggling to distinguish between when $p$ and $q$ are both false and when they are both true. For example, if I include the clause $(x \oplus (p \oplus \lnot q)) \equiv (x \oplus p \oplus \lnot q)$, then  $x$ is equivalent to whether or not both $p$ and $q$ are the same Boolean values in an assignment of variables which satisfies the formula.
It is sole curiosity which is inducing me to ask this question.

I assume you mean for the formula to be satisfied if and only if $x \iff p \land q$ (and I answered accordingly). If all we wanted were the "only if", then we could just take a formula that's never satisfied.

This is impossible.
I will prove a stronger claim: suppose that a formula $F$ (which is a conjuction of $\oplus$-clauses) has

a satisfying assignment $\alpha_{00}$ where $x \mapsto 0$, $p \mapsto 0$, $q \mapsto 0$,
a satisfying assignment $\alpha_{01}$ where $x \mapsto 0$, $p \mapsto 0$, $q \mapsto 1$, and
a satisfying assignment $\alpha_{10}$ where $x \mapsto 0$, $p \mapsto 1$, $q \mapsto 0$.

Then $F$ also has a satisfying assignment $\alpha_{11}$ where $x \mapsto 0$, $p \mapsto 1$, $q \mapsto 1$. (This means $F$ can't be logically equivalent to $x \iff p \land q$, in particular, since that is not satisfied by $\alpha_{11}$. However, it also means we can't build a gadget that plays the role of $x \iff p \land q$ by introducing extra variables.)
To see this, let's compare $\alpha_{00}$ and $\alpha_{01}$: let $S$ be the set of variables where the two assignments disagree. Then every clause of $F$ must contain an even number of literals using variables in $S$. Every time a literal is changed in a clause, the value of the clause is toggled; for the clause to be satisfied both by $\alpha_{00}$ and $\alpha_{01}$, there must be an even number of literals in the clause that change value.
Similarly, if $T$ is the set of variables where $\alpha_{00}$ and $\alpha_{10}$ disagree, then every clause of $F$ must contain an even number of literals using variables in $T$.
Now construct $\alpha_{11}$ from $\alpha_{01}$ by toggling the value of every variable in $T$. By the claim in the previous paragraph, $\alpha_{11}$ must also be a satisfying assignment.
However, we know that $x \notin T$, $p \in T$, and $q \notin T$ by the definitions of $\alpha_{00}$ and $\alpha_{10}$. Therefore, since $x\mapsto 0$ and $q \mapsto 1$ in $\alpha_{01}$, the same is true in $\alpha_{11}$; since $p \mapsto 0$ in $\alpha_{01}$, we have $p \mapsto 1$ in $\alpha_{11}$. So $\alpha_{11}$ is the assignment we wanted!

The underlying intuition here is that clauses involving only $\neg$ and $\oplus$ are (affine) linear constraints, when we think of our Boolean formulas as polynomial formulas over $\mathbb F_2$. However, $x \iff p \land q$ is a nonlinear condition, so it cannot be obtained as a conjunction of linear constraints.
Specifically, the solution set to a conjunction of $\oplus$-clauses is an affine subspace of $\mathbb F_2^n$. That's what we exploited to find $\alpha_{11}$: it's a fourth element of the affine space spanned by $\{\alpha_{00}, \alpha_{01}, \alpha_{10}\}$.
